# Django girlsでの'blog.apps.BlogConfig'

Tags: django

初心者です。Django Girlsで学習しています。

新しいアプリケーションの作成場面で「/setting.pyに'blog.apps.BlogConfig', という一行を追加します」と記載されていますが、`blog.apps.BlogConfig` とは何の意味でしょうか？blogは今回作成したapp名でしょうか？ネット上には、この意味を解説したサイトは見当たりませんでした。当然のように「・・・と記載します」としか書いてなく、内容の理解ができません。

このサンプルwebアプリはこれでいいのですが、自作するときにこれの意味がわからないと困ると思うので教えてください。

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
]
```

Comment: こちら [はじめての Django アプリ作成、その 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/3.1/intro/tutorial01/) から始まるTutorialと対比させると分るかもしれませんね。質問と同等なのは [はじめての Django アプリ作成、その2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/3.1/intro/tutorial02/) の [モデルを有効にする](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/3.1/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models) の `polls.apps.PollsConfig` でしょう。`Django Girls`の方は、その前の [プロジェクトを作成しよう！](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ja/django_start_project/) の先頭に`ここからは、小さなブログを作っていきますよ！`とあるので、それを念頭に考えてみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`blog.apps.BlogConfig`とは「`blog`フォルダの`apps.py`ファイルに書かれている`BlogConfig`クラス」のことです。

`blog.apps.BlogConfig`を書き加えている個所が`settings.py`の**INSTALLED_APPS**である点に注目してください。
`INSTALLED_APPS`はその名の通りDjangoのプロジェクトにインストールしたアプリケーションのことです。
Django Girlsの中で`python manage.py startapp blog`コマンドを使いアプリケーションを作成しましたが、Djangoのプロジェクトは`INSTALLED_APPS`にアプリケーションを記述しないと認識してくれません。

「なぜ`blog.apps.BlogConfig`のようにドットでつないで構成を表現するのか」など`INSTALLED_APPS`についてできるだけ詳細に知りたい場合は[公式ドキュメント](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#installed-apps)や[Django--INSTALLED_APPSに関してのソース解析](https://qiita.com/Syoitu/items/9926b852d8d98423f273)記事をご覧ください。

しかし初心者向けのチュートリアルでここまで難しい内容を説明すると、かえって初学者の混乱を招く可能性があるので記述を省略しているようです。

私個人の感想としてはDjango Girlsはテンポよく読み進めてサービスを作りたい方に適していると感じますが、補足を多めに読んで仕組みを理解したい方はコメントにある「[はじめての Django アプリ作成](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/3.1/intro/tutorial01/)」チュートリアルが肌にあうかもしれません。

例えば`django.contrib.admin`など`INSTALLED_APPS`の行にどんな意味があるのかについては、上記チュートリアルの[Database の設定](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/3.1/intro/tutorial02/#database-setup)の節にて大枠で説明されています。